# Has Q ever interacted with the Changelings?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

Given Q's personality, the Changelings would seem a prime example of a species he would want to interact with, test and mess with. They have a god complex, like to manipulate and control other species and bring war on the galaxy. Has Q ever been shown interacting with any member of the Changeling species in any of the Star Trek materials?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone outside the Federation has been shown to even know about the Q.

Comment: The Calamarain certainly know about the Q. Possibly the Borg also do.

Comment: Why would Q want to interact with another species with a god complex?

Comment: I doubt that the Changelings would have that sort of superiority complex in the  presence of Q. They may still make condescending remarks about "solids" if Q brings up the subject, but Q is not a solid and thus likely wouldn't care. It seems unlikely to me that the Changelings would remain smug if Q tortured them.

Comment: Q seems to be the same species as Samantha and her relatives on Bewitched. They have exactly the same powers. Samantha's mother, Endora, and her Uncle Arthur used their powers to play practical jokes, just like Q does.

Answer (score 3):

**Eh.**

I can't find anything about Q interacting with the Founders, or any Changeling besides Odo. Odo, however...

Both Q and Odo appear in the *Deep Space 9* episode "[Q-Less](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Q-Less_(episode))". In this episode, Q arrives at Deep Space 9, along with [Vash](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vash).

However, while Odo and Q both appear in this episode, they don't really interact. Q is interacting more with Sisko and O'Brien, while Odo is focusing more on Quark. As Odo is the security officer on DS9, though, he'll almost certainly know that Q was on board and will have been briefed on what he is.

As this is the only time we see Q appear in *Deep Space 9*, there aren't really many other opportunities for such a meeting to happen in canon sources.

If you include non-canon sources such as licensed novels, then *[The Q Gambit](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Q_Gambit)* by Mike Johnson might be another place where Q and Odo meet; it's a 6-part comic story where the USS Enterprise is transported into the future by Q to meet the crew of *Deep Space 9* (including Odo).

Comment: The question seems more interested in interactions with the Founders than with Odo.

Comment: @OrangeDog - I found nothing about that. Odo is the only changeling that we see ever getting near Q.